# copy formula down from previous row

Tags: excel, vba

need to copy the formula from previous row to autofill down.

```
destsht("All PO Raw Data 1-18").Columns("V3:X" & destLR).FillDown


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet, destsht As Worksheet
Dim destLR As Long, LastRow As Long


Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sht = wb.Sheets("Open PO Raw Data")


Set destwb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rc\Desktop\ALL PO RAW DATA 1-18  to present_copy.xlsx")
Set destsht = destwb.Sheets("All PO Raw Data 1-18")
destLR = destsht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
 MsgBox destLR


wb.ActiveSheet.Activate
LastRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sht.Range("A2:U" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy destsht.Range("A" & destLR)

destsht("All PO Raw Data 1-18").Columns("V3:X" & destLR).FillDown
```

the formula goes down to the last row.  The last line of code is giving me the error. I get a 438 error msg. Object doesn't support the property. I think I might need an offset for a row instead of what I show at V3.

Comment: Change `Columns` to `Range`

Comment: Same error msg with Range.

Comment: `destsht.Range("V3:X" & destLR).FillDown`

Comment: it doesn't error out, but it doesn't copy the previous formula down, it just leaves it blank.

Comment: it will copy what is in `V3:X3` down.

Comment: Are the formulas in V3:X3? or V2:X2?

Comment: it did work. How would I make it go down to the lastrow of column A

Answer (score 0):

I had to revise my code to count the rows after pasting the visible cells. Now it copies all the way down.

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet, destsht As Worksheet
Dim destLR As Long, LastRow As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sht = wb.Sheets("Open PO Raw Data")

Set destwb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rc\Desktop\ALL PO RAW DATA 1-18  to present.xlsx")
Set destsht = destwb.Sheets("All PO Raw Data 1-18")
destLR = destsht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
' MsgBox destLR

wb.ActiveSheet.Activate
LastRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sht.Range("A2:U" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy destsht.Range("A" & destLR)

Number_of_Rows = sht.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
' MsgBox Number_of_Rows

destLR = destLR + Number_of_Rows
'MsgBox destLR

destsht.Range("V3:X" & destLR).FillDown